# Old PHP include code not working anymore, how to fix?

Tags: php, html, php-include

Ok so i want to have an include code on my index.php page that will include all of the other html pages within it.  I used to do this using an id?=link.html link and this:

```
<?php 
$id = $HTTP_GET_VARS['id'];
if ( !$id || $id == "" )
 { 
 $number=10;
 include("news/show_news.php");
 } 
else
 { 
 include "$id"; 
} 
?>
```

but apparantly http_get_vars is unrecognized or something?  How can I fix this so that it will work? Or if things have changed, why should I not use this kind of thing for includes?

Comment: `include` still working (with my php version, about 5.4.x). `$HTTP_GET_VARS['id']` = it's really old. why don't you use `GET` or `POST` method?
so the html : `page.php?id=the_id`
php : `$id = $_GET['id']`

Comment: this code makes security issue, please refer to manuals, books, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_GET` to fetch the query string parameter by GET request, e.g.

```
index.php?id=123
```

The `id` value can be obtained by `$_GET['id']`.

p.s. your PHP codes are really old.

Comment: <?php $id = $_GET['id']; if ( !$id || $id == "" ) { $number=10;  include("news/show_news.php"); } else { include "$id"; } ?>   this is what ive got now and its not quite working, its saying id is undefined

Comment: and ya lol these codes are from like 10 years ago, ive just recently been getting back into programming now that html5 is in full swing

Comment: What is the Request URL ? e.g. `index.php?id=123` ?

Comment: @user2922030 Don't include a user provided file name! It's a security risk.

Comment: the request url would be any link on the page that begins with ?id= so for example if i clicked the link ?id=contact.html or ?id=about.html, the contents of those pages would go where the include code is on the index.php page.  so that on the index.php page it would show my news instead

Comment: and thanks for the good looks John V :) ill be more careful

Comment: You sure `about.html` exists in the same path with your request file? change `include` to `require` and turn on error reporting to debug.

Comment: about.html was just an example, my goal is to fix it so it will include literally any link that leads with ?id=, of course only one at a time, else include my news stuff

Comment: suggest to rewrite the logic from the beginning

Comment: not sure how to ask this without asking you to write the code for me, but how would i do that?  im super rusty on php syntax

Answer (score 0):

solved with the following:

```
        <?php 

        if (!empty($_GET['id'])) { 
        $id = $_GET['id'];  
        $id = basename($id);  
        include("$id");  
        } else {
        include("news/newsfilename.php");
        }

        ?>
```

and

```
             <a href="index.php?id=pagename.html">
             Page Name
             </a>
```

as the html

Comment: this code makes security issue, please refer to manuals, books, etc. at least please warn users this code is not safe at all